Would Camus say that any philosopher who denies the absurd is intellectually dishonest?
I have been reading Camus' 'The Myth of Sisyphus', and it appears quite clear to me that Camus takes the existence of the absurd as a fundamental truth about  the human condition's interaction with the Universe (although he does paradoxically state in multiple occasions that the human mind is unable to assert absolute truths about the world without running into contradiction).
Indeed Camus states explicitly that his essay will take the recognition of the existence of the absurd as a starting point.
"I am interested - let me repeat again - not so much in absurd discoveries as in their consequences." p. 16
Now my question here is, what if a philosopher/scientist or anyone who engages in such inquires does not reach his conclusion as the existence of the absurd, in which afterwards he could join Camus in trying to figure out how to address the conclusion? What if one at the end of his philosophizing reachers the conclusion of God (which is different in this case from the leap of faith that Camus goes on the criticize (one is a conviction of the meaning of existence, the other is a hopeful response to what appears to be a complete lack of meaning to existence.)
Would Camus state that the individual who doesnt reach the absurd is being intellectually dishonest? Would he state that the methodologies he used were faulty and so on?
Thank you.

The absurd is the fundamental intuition of Camus' philosophy, like the cogito for Descartes. Philosophy and thinking in general, needs starting points: we cannot prove everything. Starting from the the philosopher develops its arguments, analyze critically them  debates, and so on.

I agree with @MauroALLEGRANZA. But it may still be valid (and fruitful) to ask again then -- How is this starting point developed/expressed? Is it really his starting point? That is, where is Sisyphus' presumed happiness coming from? Isn't this a blind jump as well? ("After all we are our choices." That's very well, but we're not gods and Camus seems to presume a sui generis autonomy of persons. ) Anyway, to argue that those who don't start from this are intellectually honest, seems itself intellectually dishonest. I don't believe Camus would do so.

The problem is also that the argument against suicide in the Myth is very unsatisfactory. It's similar to Freud's dictum that we cannot imagine our own death (because when dead we're no longer there to imagine anything). To which Russell replied: I can imagine it very well. I will have ceased to exist and my body will be rotting in the ground. -- But presenting an invalid/unsatisfactory argument does not make someone intellectually dishonest... The value of the Myth doesn't depend on this arguement being valid.

@mudskipper - agreed, but the starting points, albeit not "proved", are "argumented": the complete theory that the philosopher develops from them IS the (only) ground for the fundamental intuition.

Russell may have spoken in more suave and measured tones. But he said about the same as Camus

The world is rational, not absurd; it perfectly follows its physical laws. The human search for meaning is a consequence of how our brains work, which is a consequence of those perfectly rational and consistent physical laws. The universe isn't absurd, but some people's conception of it might be.

I agree that Camus’  ‘The Myth of Sisyphus’

takes the existence of the absurd as a fundamental truth about the
human condition's interaction with the Universe.

But Camus does not present arguments. He appeals to us, he presents a thesis. In my eyes Camus is a hybrid between a philosopher and a novellist.
From a philosophical point of view it is easy to resolve the seemingly absurd clash between the human need for clarity and rational understanding on one hand, and the non-rational world which remains silent on the other hand:

From a first person stance one may - erroneously - expect that nature
notices human needs.

But from the third person stance, which is the objective
viewpoint, nature existed billions of years without any humans and their needs.
From the objective viewpoint there is no absurdity. Because there is no reason why the blueprint of the universe should incorporate human needs.


Camus does not tell us what he thinks about the motivation of philosophers, who do not accept his thesis, or about their methodology. Hence one had to speculate on this point.

Is it not also a form of philosophy to take some premisse -- in this case the absence of any transcendent source of real value or meaning -- and develop this into a more or less coherent view of human life, investigating the implications for personhood and ethics? Especially since there is no accepted "first philosophy" anymore; anything presented as such is contentious and a target of more questions. -- I would say it is. Some statements need to be taken as similar to axioms - then we run with that -- using reason and basic experience -- and see how far it gets us.

You say it's "easy" to resolve the apparent incongruity - but what you describe is a kind of stoic attitude -- which also happens to appeal to me -- but which I don't see as necessarily "easy" or as more truthful or fruitful (to work out into an ethics for instance).

@mudskipper When favouring an anthropocentric stance you may get Camus’ “axiom” of absurdity. On the contrary, from the viewpoint of the Copernicus principle the universe has no centre and no distinguished entities. Is stoicism a position alike radical?
